# Read and load Dynamic Files into PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I can connect to data source using `PowerBi`

my filename: DataValuation.csv

However, source filename changes everyday with a timestamp `DataValuation11112019.csv`

I will need to read files everyday with current date at suffix of file as above

```
    let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Data\DataValuation.csv"), null, true),
        Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",
          {{"Reference", Int64.Type}, {"COUNTS", Int64.Type}})
    in
        #"Changed Type"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Folder` data source in this case. In the model you will get all columns from your CSV files and additional columns (e.g. for the file name, extension, etc.), which you can remove in case you don't need them.

See [Combine files (binaries) in Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-combine-binaries) for example.

Comment: This is still a manual select , i would like something like this as source DataValuation+ddmmyyyy.csv in the query edit

Comment: No, you will select only the folder, where these files will be saved. Then Power BI will pick all the files in this folder. If you need to somehow filter them, you can do this based on their name.

Comment: I have tried that, it will be robust as i have more than 10000 files in the folder and i really want to load a particular file based on its timestamp appended to its file name

Comment: Probably you are looking for something like [incremental refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-premium-incremental-refresh), but this is Premium only feature. The other way is to change your ETL process.

Comment: cant we load a filename dynamically without ETL processes, `Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("H:\Data_DATA\DocId_data_08112019.xlsx"), null, true),`  file name as DocId_data_(timestamp).xlsx ?

Comment: Probably yes, but this solution is very fragile. What if Power BI miss one file (e.g. a refresh fails)? You should not rely on current date, but load all the data since last load.